# Selecting map objects using ol.source.TileWMS in open layers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I am using open layers 3, 
and I am using this code for displaying the map:

```
wmsSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
           url: 'http://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/wms',
           params: { 'LAYERS': 'ne:ne' },
           serverType: 'geoserver',
           crossOrigin: ''
      });
       var wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
           source: wmsSource
       });
```

I am using dragbox to make the rectangular selection and when I do the shift + drag I am not able to select the objects in map. Can somebody please help me on how to achieve it?
This is the code I am using for rectangular selection.

```
dragBox.on('boxend', function(e) {
  // features that intersect the box are added to the collection of  
  // selected features, and their names are displayed in the "info"
  // div
  var info = [];
  var extent = dragBox.getGeometry().getExtent();
  wmsSource .forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent(extent, function(feature) {
    selectedFeatures.push(feature);
    info.push(feature.get('name'));
  });
  if (info.length > 0) {
   infoBox.innerHTML = info.join(', ');
 }
});   `
```

Comment: You got your answer, don't forget the feedback!

Answer (score 3):

You use a TileWMS source, which is a collection of images (tiles) rendered on the WMS server. OpenLayers does not know about the features used to render the images. Because of this, `forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent` is only available on vector sources.

You could create a WMS `getFeatureInfo`-request in the boxend callback, to load the feature information from the server.

Alternatively, you could create a vector source containing the features you want and use for the `forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent` call.

Comment: Thank you very much Alvin. I will try it and get back to you.

Comment: Great. Please mark the answer as accepted (it makes it clear that the issue is not in need of new replies, and encourages people like me to help answer questions).