# Get the name (or id) of the tile layer clicked in the onclick event (openlayers 3)

Tags: openlayers-3

I created my layers like this:

```
var wms_bmid_parcels = new ol.source.TileWMS({
    url: 'http://176.7.69.145:8080/geoserver/wms',
    params: { 'LAYERS': 'bmid-parcels' },
    serverType: 'geoserver',
});
```

In the  `map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {....}`

I need to know what layer was clicked. The

```
map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function (feature, layer) {
```

does not work since it work only for vector layers.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

TIA

JJ.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32677976/4640499

Comment: How about accepting the given answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`map.forEachLayerAtPixel`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.Map.html#forEachLayerAtPixel), which will call your callback for any raster layers that are not transparent on the given pixel.

Comment: Thank you Alvin. The problem is that my layers are like:  var wms_bmid_pipes = new ol.source.TileWMS({
             url: 'http://173.4.62.150:8080/geoserver/wms',
             params: { 'LAYERS': 'bmid-pipes' },
             serverType: 'geoserver',
         });
JJ.

Comment: @user91542 Yes, you wrote that in your question. forEachLayerAtPixel should work for TileWMS layers. What is your issue?

Comment: Hello again Alvin, It is not working. Here is the code: var wms_bmid_pipes = new ol.source.TileWMS({
             url: 'http://175.4.60.160:8080/geoserver/wms',
             params: { 'LAYERS': 'bmid-pipes' },
               });
];
    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: layers,
        target: 'map',
         view: view,
         overlays: [overlay]
        });

    map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature, layer) {
   console.log(layer);
        return feature;   
  });

Comment: You are using forEachFeatureAtPixel. My answer is about forEachLayerAtPixel. They are not the same

Comment: In the click event layer and feature are undefined.  Thanks . JJ.

Comment: Yes it worked but I need to know which layer is at the clicked pixel and I don't see how to get this information. layer is still undefined.  map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {
  var feature = map.forEachLayerAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature, layer) {
   console.log(layer);
        return feature;   
  });

Comment: Hi Alvin. Just to give you a big thank you for your help. I figured out using the forEachLayerAtPixel. Life is good. Beste regards.  JJ.

Comment: well then if the suggestion worked then you can mark Alvin's answer true . If possible share how you got it right .this can help other too.