# How to change from WMS Ednpoint to WFS endpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers-3

In my application I am displaying totally 36 layers as a group. I am using WMS Endpoint and loading the geoserver data. I want to fetch all the features in particular layers which i have loaded with the geoserver data. It consists of lines, polygon etc.

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/examples/vector-wfs.html?q=wms

This ablove example gives how to fetch all the features using WFS endpoint.

So how can i change it from WMS to WFS endpoint to fetch all the features in the particular layer.

Please help me out. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Off-Topic: Try to finish your questions.

Comment: Hi Jonatas walker. I am loading the layers using WMS endpoints and it also loads with featues like line,polygon etc using the dragbox i am not able to select the features. So can you please help me out. How to select the features in the WMS layer.

Comment: I don't know how to help in this question. My first comment is about that [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32608892/4640499) you didn't finish.